# Sci-fi movie where the male protagonist knows a woman with three or more children, all named after continents

Tags: story-identification, movie

All I can remember about this sci-fi movie is that the male protagonist is acquainted with a woman who lives in a very small apartment on the top floor of a building.  There is a bright neon sign that shines in the window.  She has at least three children, all named after continents.  One I remember is Australia.  Anyone remember the title?

The male protagonist is sort of an un-hero, clumsy and absent-minded.

The film is in English.  It probably was released between 2000 and 2010.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: In particular, it'd helpful to know when you watched this movie, when you think it was made, what was the general premise of the story, and what specific sci-fi elements were present in the film.

Comment: Added a little more info.  Curiously, I can't remember the premise of the film!!!

Comment: *[Mrs. Wiggs of the Cabbage Patch](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0025523/?ref_=tt_urv)* has the girls named after continents including Australia Wiggs, but there's nothing sci-fi, and I haven't seen anything about a neon sign (it's also set in the early 1900s with nothing sci-fi).

Comment: @nuggethead - Can you recall any specific sci-fi elements at all, like any specific technology? If the film you're asking about doesn't have any sci-fi or fantasy elements, then this question isn't on-topic here.